# Jquery .One() for an entire class

Tags: jquery, function, class

```
$('.cp-play').one("click", function(){
//Code stuff
}
```

I have multiple elements of class .cp-play. Instead of having a one() click handler event for each element I want to have it for entire class. E.g. User clicks on one of the .cp-play and even if they click another one with same class name it won't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.off` in the handler:

```
$('.cp-play').on('click', function() {
    $('.cp-play').off('click');
    // Code stuff
});
```

If you have multiple click handlers and just want to disable one of them, use a named function so you can refer to it in the `.off()` call

```
function cp_play_click() {
    $('.cp-play').off('click', cp_play_click);
    // code stuff
});
$('.cp-play').on('click', cp_play_click);
```

Comment: That works but I have other $('.cp-play').click functions that stopped working now because it unbinded all handlers.

Any way to just unbind that particular function only?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can unbind just a single handler by using a named function.